# Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid. A minimum of one .ssdl artifact must be supplied

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, ado.net

I have a class that is going to execute entity framework based queries. This class is a general class and is `DbContext` independent class(I mean there is no `ssdl` or `semiliar` files). In this class I am going to execute raw sql queries too. in order to this I add a method like:

```
 Return _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery(Of String)(query).FirstOrDefault()
```

to execute scalars. but there is an error in this stage that says:

```
Additional information: Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid. A minimum of one .ssdl artifact must be supplied.
```

When I was going to create new instance of `DbContext`, I had passed this connection string to it:

```
metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDb;integrated security=true;
```

Error Detail:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147024809
Message=Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid. A minimum of one .ssdl artifact must be supplied. 
Source=EntityFramework
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityUtil.CheckArgumentEmpty[T](IEnumerable`1& enumerableArgument,  Func`2 errorMessage, String argumentName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__4()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadAndCheckItemCollection[T](Func`1 itemCollectionLoader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.<>c__DisplayClass16.<.ctor>b__f()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace, Boolean required)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.InitializeMappingViewCacheFactory(DbContext owner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor, ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, Translator translator, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ObjectContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery[TElement](String sql, Nullable`1 streaming, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQueryAsIEnumerator[TElement](String sql, Nullable`1 streaming, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery(Type elementType, String sql, Nullable`1 streaming, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlNonSetQuery.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at IdeaDataAccess.EF.EntityFrameworkQueryPerformer`1.ExecuteScalar(String query)
   at IdeaBusiness.DatabaseCore.Core`2.ExecuteScalar(String query)
   at IdeaBusiness.DatabaseCore.Facade.ExecuteScalar(String query)
   at IdeaComponent.IdeaComponent.IdeaGridView.OnRowCreated(GridViewRowEventArgs e) in D:\Solutions\IdeaCenter\Source Code\IdeaCenterV2\IdeaComponent\Components\GridView\IdeaGridView.vb:line 515
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind()
   at WebApplication1.WebForm1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\idea\Desktop\New folder\WebForm1.aspx.vb:line 8
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   InnerException:
```

Comment: what version of SQL Server Database are you using may I ask..?
take a look at these http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716756(v=vs.100).aspx || http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx

Comment: Also, the stack trace from the error would be useful.

Comment: @DJKRAZE this is working fine when I use it without raw sql queries. How ever my SQL Server version is 2012

Comment: @simonatrcl Stack Trace is now added to the my question body

Comment: Looking at the Stack Trace, this is very deep into the guts of the Entity Framework. I assume that you are running under Visual Studio. I would Clean the solution, and then rebuild it, and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally find a solution for this problem. I added a reference to EntityFramework.dll in my UI and then pass typical connection string to my Biz layer and create a DbContext object based on this, thus executing functions in DataAccess done with no error. Thank you for all.
If you need to know more about my solution, please tell me to illustrate it

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your Connection String, it looks a bit lacking. This is one from a current project, with various linebreaks added to make it easier to read:

```
          <connectionStrings>
             <add name="PowerDespatchConnection" 
    connectionString="

metadata=res://*/PowerDespatch.csdl|
         res://*/PowerDespatch.ssdl|
         res://*/PowerDespatch.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;data source=athena;initial catalog=RCDev;Integrated Security=SSPI;App=EntityFramework&quot;
           " 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

You are missing the csdl, ssdl, and msl sections. (PowerDespatch is the name of the Model.) You should find the matching files under your EF project folder, in obj\Debug\edmxResourcesToEmbed.

If these are missing, then something about how you created the Model is not right.

Comment: I have no specific model, in order to say it's name in my connection string

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: when using EF6.Effort in unit tests using model first, make sure that the metadata file names in the connection string are correct AND the model assembly (containing the .edmx file) is loaded before you establish a connection.

---

Long form: I ran also into this exception, in the context of using EntityFramework during unit tests with EF6.Effort

What this error boils down to is that the .ssdl file can't be found, in my case the exception occurs when trying to create the DB connection with

```
Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient("name=MyEntities")
```

Make sure that the connectionString contains the correct names for the model files (MyModel in the example below, as mentioned above you should find them in `obj/Debug/edmxResourcesToEmbed`, it's also the name of you MyModel.edmx file, or by looking into the resources of your model assembly, e.g. with ILSpy)

```
<add name="testDb" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;provider=...
```

You must use the relative path from `obj/Debug/edmxResourcesToEmbed` to the `.ssdl` file! If the `.ssdl` is at `obj/Debug/edmxResourcesToEmbed/MyModel.ssdl` then you need to use `res://*/MyModel.ssdl`; if it is at `obj/Debug/edmxResourcesToEmbed/Extra/Directories/Just/For/Testing/MyModel.ssdl` then you need to use `res://*/Extra/Directories/Just/For/Testing/MyModel.ssdl`.

Finally, make sure that the model's assembly is actually loaded before you make the above call (Effort.EF6 resolves the ssdl file from the currently loaded assemblies), e.g. just accessing a type from the assembly with

```
typeof(MyDbContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

The same error fired for me also on Visual Studio 2017. All I did was to click on Clean Solution then Rebuild and ran the app again to find that it is now resolved.
I hope this helps.