# Using Effort with EF6 in a DB First approach

Tags: entity-framework-6, effort

I'm using the Model First approach with EF6 and I'm trying to use [Entity Framework Effort](http://entityframework-effort.net/) to develop in-memory tests.

Here is what I do in my test:

```
var inMemoryConnection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient("name=MyEntities");
var inMemoryContext = new MyEntities(inMemoryConnection);
```

MyEntities:

```
public partial class MyEntities: DbContext
{
    public MyEntities(DbConnection dbConnection)
        : base(dbConnection, contextOwnsConnection: true)
    {
    }
```

When I run the tests, I get an error saying I didn't specify any [key] attributes which is normal since I am not using a Code First approach. Therefor, the OnModelCreating method is called and shouldn't have to.

Is there a way to use Effort in a Model First design without having to add these attributes?

Thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found my mistake.

Turns out Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient is used for Code-First.

Instead if you're working with a .edmx, Model-First, it is Effort.**Entity**ConnectionFactory.CreateTransient("name=MyEntities") you have to use.

Comment: This didn't work for me - it still uses the actual database instead of an in-memory one. What does your ``app.config`` look like?

Comment: @MattKoch I had to add `<provider invariantName="Effort.Provider" type="Effort.Provider.EffortProviderServices,Effort" />` into the `<providers>` section of my app.config

Comment: @MattKoch How do you know it is using the actual db?

Comment: in case you're getting an exception

    `Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid. A minimum of one .ssdl artifact must be supplied` ...

What's also relevant is that you need to have the model assembly (containing the edmx file) loaded BEFORE the above call     `Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient("name=MyEntities")`

i.e. just doing a 
`typeof(MyDbContext)` before the call will do the trick.

Answer (score 9):

I too had a bit of a difficult time in trying to get Effort to work with a DB first, or model first as it's also known, approach. This is what I did to make it work:

- Download the Effort.EF6 nuget package
- Add the effort.provider to the entity-framework config section:

```
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Effort.Provider" type="Effort.Provider.EffortProviderServices,Effort" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

- Replace the sql-provider with the Effort-provider in the connection-string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="testDb" providerName="Effort.Provider" connectionString="metadata=res://*/StaginDB.csdl|res://*/StaginDB.ssdl|res://*/StaginDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=testDB;initial catalog=foobaroo;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"  />
  </connectionStrings>
```

- If your model-first context doesn't offer a constructor you can inject a connection into, you can modify your tt-template to do so:

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
{

    // I added this constructor so I could inject a db-connection into the context:
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>(System.Data.Common.DbConnection dbConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection) 
        : base(dbConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
        {
    }

    // Original constructor
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    {
<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoa.... etc. etc.
```

- And we can now use that constructor to instantiate a connection, and an Effort-based in-memory db-context based on this connection:

```
System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection = Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient("name=KPDBSTAGINGEntities");
TestDbContext testDbContext = new testDbContext(connection, false);

TestDbContext.your-entity.add( new your-entity() { etc. tec. });
TestDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Hope this helps.

P.S. Others have had to add a db-provider-factory section to their config. This was not required for me, but maybe for you:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Effort.Provider" invariant="Effort.Provider" description="Effort.Provider" type="Effort.Provider.EffortProviderFactory,Effort" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Comment: I was getting an error after setting the connection string. This comment solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/77005361/6735035